# How to subscribe to popup window opening in System.Windows.Automation

Tags: c#, windows, testing, ui-automation

I'm trying to use `System.Windows.Automation` library to do some UI testing, and was able to make some progress, but I am unable to subscribe to the event of creating a popup window in my app. I've tried to use `Automation.AddStructureChangedEventHandler` on the root (desktop object) as well as on the window, but that didn't work. I also tried using different scopes, which also didn't help.

```
AutomationElement desktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;
AutomationElement app = desktop
    .FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty,
            "Name of the App", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase));

ActivateWindow(app);

AutomationElement appWindow = app
    .FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty,
            ControlType.Window));

// Find a button that opens a popup window and click it
AutomationElement button = appWindow
    .FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)
    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[8];

MoveMouseToAndClick(button);

Automation.AddStructureChangedEventHandler(desktop, TreeScope.Descendants, setupWindowOpen);
```

The `setupWindowOpen` handler fires sometimes, but it looks like that happens for other apps, not mine (I'm seeing Internet Explorer ids on the sender element object). 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pop up controls are tricky as they could be located either directly under the desktop or under your application, or maybe anywhere else (direct child of desktop is best guess). I suggest you use the WinSDK_AccEvent.exe utility shipped with Microsoft's SDK to test the popup's behavior with various events such as: WindowOpened, StructureChanged, ToolTipOpened on the desktop and on your automated application. This should get you the correct events to subscribe to and in what scope. **Important note:** If you are using the managed version of the UI Automation framework, you best migrate to the native version as the managed one has limitations on what it can capture and several performance bugs that just can't be overcome. Also it is no longer officially supported apparently. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to `WindowOpenedEvent` (see this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowopenedevent?view=netframework-4.8)). It looks easy, but I am having problems getting that to work.

If you are still interested in UI testing and are familiar with Selenium driver, you can try my implementation available at https://github.com/kfrajtak/WinAppDriver.