# How to get notified after calling Process.CloseWindow() if main window is not shown in taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Client application, in which the main window's task bar icon is hidden.

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ShowInTaskBar=false;
}
```

Now I am running this WPF application from a process:

```
process.CloseWindow();
```

When I call the above code my WPF application is not closed.
It is working fine when I set the ShowInTaskbar value as true.

I can only change the code belonging to the WPF Client application, not the host application.

How can I:

1. Get notified from CloseWindow the the API is being called.
2. Shut down the client application when the task bar icon is
   invisible?

Comment: Use System.Windows.Automation to find that window back.  Sample code is unusually hard to find, I see some in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35096297/17034).

Comment: If i write code to get window back that i have to write in host application.
But i don't have access of host application.